# What is the timeout value for a non-blocking Python socket when reading?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, timeout

I'm using Python 2.7 and am working with some legacy code.  It sets a socket in non blocking mode with:

```
self._socket.setblocking(0)
self._socket.settimeout(0)
```

My question is, when doing a read, what determines the timeout on the socket?  Will it be the default used by the TCP stack on the OS?  If so, on Linux how would that be changed?  Also, will the write timeout be the same as the read timeout?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) (emphasis mine):

> In non-blocking mode, if a `recv()` call doesn’t find any data, or if a
>   `send()` call can’t *immediately* dispose of the data, a `error` exception
>   is raised.

So it seems as though the "timeout" is an instantaneous check.  If there is no data available or a write can't be made exactly when you call the function, you will receive an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Following is from the help of `socket.settimeout`

> settimeout(...) method of socket._socketobject instance
>        settimeout(timeout)
>
> Set a timeout on socket operations.  'timeout' can be a float,
>      giving in seconds, or None.  Setting a timeout of None disables
>     the timeout feature and is equivalent to `setblocking(1)`.
>      Setting a timeout of zero is the same as `setblocking(0)`.

So I am not sure why both `setblocking(0)` and `settimeout(0)` both is done above. This means `read` is immediately going to return with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if there's no data available. When the other end closes connection, `read` will return with a value of `0`.

Read timeout would make sense only in 'blocking' state where after the time equal to timeout has elapsed and there's no data to read, the read should return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

In general that is not going to affect `write` timeout. When you set socket to non-blocking and if the 'write buffers' are full (which would rarely happen, unless there's a rather 'slow' receiver) and if `write` is likely to block,it should return immediately with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` and then the onus is on the application to make sure the `write` is issued again.

Comment: you mean `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` instead of `EINTR` (the latter may be raised if signal is received during a (blocking?) system call on the current Python version. In Python 3.5+, you should not see `EINTR`: [PEP 0475 -- Retry system calls failing with EINTR](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/))

Comment: I am sorry - yes it's`EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`